# Alias attriibute for column names in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, alias

So, I have a db which was setup for an old php app and I cannot touch the way the DB is done.

However, I have some column name in the db that are using some restricted words in Ruby like "class"

So to make it work, I used `alias_attribute`.

But it's not working. Here is the code:

```
class Contractor < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "contractors"
  alias_attribute :class_type, :class
  attr_accessible :about, :alias, :business_entity, :business_logo, :business_name, :city, :class, :county, :created, :email, :founded, :metroarea, :nid, :phone, :state, :status, :street_address, :uid, :zipcode
end
```

here are the errors:

```
1.9.3-p125 :001 > Contractor.last
SyntaxError: /Users/snoopy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activemodel-3.2.13/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:345: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '='
    from /Users/snoopy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activemodel-3.2.13/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:343:in `module_eval'
    from /Users/snoopy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activemodel-3.2.13/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:343:in `define_optimized_call'
    from /Users/snoopy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activemodel-3.2.13/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:227:in `block in alias_attribute'
    from /Users/snoopy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activemodel-3.2.13/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:224:in `each'
    from /Users/snoopy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activemodel-3.2.13/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:224:in `alias_attribute'
    from /Users/snoopy/Projects/buildzoom/ruby/service_request/app/models/contractor.rb:3:in `<class:Contractor>'
    from /Users/snoopy/Projects/buildzoom/ruby/service_request/app/models/contractor.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/snoopy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `load'
    from /Users/snoopy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `block in load_file'
    from /Users/snoopy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:639:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Users/snoopy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:468:in `load_file'
    from /Users/snoopy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:353:in `require_or_load'
    from /Users/snoopy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /Users/snoopy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
    from /Users/snoopy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `each'
    from /Users/snoopy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/snoopy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /Users/snoopy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/snoopy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

and

```
1.9.3-p125 :003 > Contractor.where(:zipcode => "94111")
  Contractor Load (648.6ms)  SELECT `contractors`.* FROM `contractors` WHERE `contractors`.`zipcode` = '94111'
(Object doesn't support #inspect)
 =>
```

The last one only appear when I remove the alias_attribute otherwise it's the same error as first one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there is the gem [safe_attributes](https://github.com/bjones/safe_attributes) who is doing the work.
It's working perfectly so far.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the alias name you gave ":class"
class is one of the ActiveRecord methods
you can see it by running this command

```
Contractor.first.methods
```

defining this alias simply "override" it in some way and interrupt to rails operation